# imagemagick - print 2 pdf pages on one A4 sheet

Tags: pdf, printing, imagemagick, merge

For university, i like to print out my professors scripts. They usually use beamer- or powerpoint presentations throughout the lectures.

My goal is to have two presentation sheets on one A4 page.

With Adobe Acrobat, this seems to be not so big of a deal but since i switched to Linux completely, i would like to find a solution that works fine without having to use acroread, pdfstudio or another closed source program.

I tried printing with evince, okular and several other applications (which all feature multi-page-printing-options), but the results were often not rotated incorrectly or where scaled much too small. Not having a print-preview doesn't make things easier.

So my newest idea would be to create a new .pdf with imagemagick and have two sheets on one page, one above the other so that i can print it out as big as possible.

Imagemagick should be capable of doing that, but i don't know the right commands!

If there's anyone knowing other/better solutions to the problem, you're of course welcome to share!

Comment: Oh that's a good one, thank you! I originally thought that Imagemagick would be the best tool for this job, but in the meantime realized that there are better Options. I'll delete this post!

Answer (score 0):

**Sejda PDF** can also help you do that, please try the **N-up tool**:

1. Go to https://www.sejda.com/n-up-pdf
2. Select your PDF document
3. Choose 2-up (selected by default)
4. Click 'N-up PDF' and wait for the task to complete, then click 'Download' to save your resulting document.

Free service for documents up to 200 pages or 50 Mb and 3 times per hour.

There's also a [desktop alternative to the online service](https://www.sejda.com/desktop) that works on Linux, Mac and Windows.

I'm one of the developers.